# Crosswalk and Adobe SDK compilation on Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, adobe, crosswalk

We have been tasked with developing an embedded crosswalk application on android that uses Adobe SDK to allow users to edit images.

It works fine on API 20 and upper but with API 19 (min supported) it crashes with the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.xwalk.core.XWalkLibraryLoader
>
> ```
>  at org.xwalk.core.XWalkActivityDelegate.<init>(XWalkActivityDelegate.java:40)
>  at org.xwalk.core.XWalkActivity.onCreate(XWalkActivity.java:211)
>  at com.dantebus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
>  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

We tried to fix the gradle script with no success. The only way to make it work has been to remove Adobe SDK completely including related code and libraries.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

in case is relevant for someone i found the problem:

my application class didn't extend MultiDexApplication